# Switch on number of arguments given to a macro

Tags: optional-arguments, xparse

I want to define a macro that does different things depending on the number of (optional) arguments given to it. Is this possible? How?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\MyCommand}{ g g g }{
% if 1 parameter
   thing for 1 parameter #1
% else if 2 parameters
   thing for 2 parameters #1 #2
% else if 3 parameters
   thing for 3 parameters #1 #2 #3
}

\begin{document}
\MyCommand{one}
\MyCommand{one}{two}
\MyCommand{one}{two}{three}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you know this is not recommended, as while we provide the `g` argument in `xparse` it's non-standard LaTeX syntax.

Comment: right, yeah, it should probably be { o o o } I guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is *yes*.   You can use `\IfNoValueTF` as a switch.

It's probably better to go with `o` instead of `g`.

I think the code is actually cleaner using `\ExplSyntaxOn`.  Some might say easier to read (not all the distracting `%` to read)--- others might not. ;)

With `\ExplSyntaxOn` you will have to use `~` for spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\testing}{ ooo }
    {
        \IfNoValueTF {#1} { \texttt{Hello ~ World} }{
            \IfNoValueTF {#2} { \textit{#1} }{
                \IfNoValueTF {#3}  { \textbf{#1}:\textsf{#2} }
                    { \textbf{#3}:\textit{#2}:\textsf{#1} }
            }}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\testing[One][Two][Three]

\testing[One][Two]

\testing[One]

\testing
\end{document}
```

## A LaTeX3 Solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g__my_options_count_int
\int_gset:Nn \g__my_options_count_int {3}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testing}{ ooo }
    {
        \IfNoValueT {#3}{  \int_gdecr:N \g__my_options_count_int }
        \IfNoValueT {#2}{  \int_gdecr:N \g__my_options_count_int }
        \IfNoValueT {#1}{  \int_gdecr:N \g__my_options_count_int }
        \int_case:nnn { \g__my_options_count_int }
            {
                {  3  }{\textbf{#3}:\textit{#2}:\textsf{#1}}
                {  2  }{\textbf{#1}:\textsf{#2}}
                {  1  }{\textit{#1}}
            }{
                \texttt{Hello ~ World}
            }
        \int_gset:Nn \g__my_options_count_int {3}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\testing[One][Two][Three]

\testing[One][Two]

\testing[One]

\testing
\end{document}
```

## All the above produce:

[image]

Comment: »not all the distracting `%` to read)« - one _can_ get used to them ;)

Comment: @cgnieder true.  But with `\ExplSyntaxOn` you also don't have to worry about whether you forgot any `%`.

Comment: If there's no first optional argument there's no second and third either. I'd go from the first to the third: try it and you'll see that the order is more natural.

Comment: @egreg So right. :(  And it would be cleaner.